# My Django-ajax Like Button is not working..?

Tags: html, jquery, django

I had tried several times to fix this but not successfull, likes count are all updating when I use the admin panel but not in html template..

**views.py**

```
from common.decorators import ajax_required
@ajax_required
@login_required
@require_POST
def like_post(request):
    # image_id = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('id'))
    image_id = request.POST.get('id')
    action = request.POST.get('action')
    if image_id and action:
        try:
            image = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
            if action == 'like':
                image.likes.add(request.user)
            else:
                image.likes.remove(request.user)
            return JsonResponse({'status':'ok'})
        except:
            pass
    return JsonResponse({'status':'error'})
```

**post_view.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block title %}Users Posts{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container-fluid">
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" value="Post">
    </form>
</div>

{% for post in posts %}
    <div class="w3-container w3-card w3-white w3-round w3-margin"><br>
            <img src="{% if post.user.profile.photo %} {{post.user.profile.photo.url}} 
            {% else %}{% static 'img/user.png' %}{% endif %}" alt="Avatar" class="w3-left w3-circle w3-margin-right" style="width:60px">
            <span class="w3-right w3-opacity">{{ post.created }}</span>
            <h4>{{ post.user|title }}</h4><br>
            <hr class="w3-clear">
            <p>{{ post.title }}</p>
            {% if post.image %}
            <div style="max-width:100%;height:auto;object-fit: cover;" class="img-fluid">
                <img src="{{ post.image.url }}" class="img-fluid" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;object-fit: cover;">
            </div>
            <p>{{ post.description }}</p>
            {% endif %}
            {% with total_likes=post.likes.count users_like=post.likes.all %}
            <div class="image-info">
              <div>
                <span class="count">
                  <span class="total">{{ total_likes }}</span>
                  like{{ total_likes|pluralize }}
                </span>
                 <a href="#" data-id="{{ post.id }}" data-action="{% if request.user in users_like %}un{% endif %}like"    class="like button mb-3">
                   {% if request.user not in users_like %}
                       Like
                    {% else %}
                       Unlike
                    {% endif %}
                 </a>
              </div>
            </div>   
        {% endwith %} 
</div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% include 'post/pagination.html' with page=posts %}

{% endblock %}

{% block domready %}
  $('a.like').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('{% url "post:like" %}',
      {
        id: $(this).data('id'),
        action: $(this).data('action')
      },
      function(data){
        if (data['status'] == 'ok')
        {
          var previous_action = $('a.like').data('action');


          // toggle data-action
          $('a.like').data('action', previous_action == 'like' ?
          'unlike' : 'like');
          // toggle link text
          $('a.like').text(previous_action == 'like' ? 'Unlike' :
          'Like');

          // update total likes
          var previous_likes = parseInt($('span.count .total').text());
          $('span.count .total').text(previous_action == 'like' ?
          previous_likes + 1 : previous_likes - 1);
        }
      }
    );
  });
{% endblock %}
```

**base.html**

```
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
      <script src="{% static 'js/js.cookie.min.js' %}"></script>
      <script>
          var csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');
          function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
            // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
            return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
          }
          $.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
              if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
              }
            }
          });

          $(document).ready(function(){
            {% block domready %}
            {% endblock %}
          });
      </script>
```

**urls.py**

```
    from django.urls import path
    from post import views
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.conf.urls.static import static


    app_name = 'post'
    urlpatterns = [
            path('',views.post_list,name='post_list_view'),
            path('like/',views.like_post,name='like'),
    ]
```

This the entire code when I tried to modify the ajax function the like button changes and then it will change all other likes present in the post_view.html, where it contains the all other posts in the same page..

Comment: Please describe your problem. What does it mean that button is not working?

Comment: Thank you sir for your kindly response, I fixed it sir.. Once again thank you..